# Illegal instance declaraion when using tuples

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Messing around in Haskell getting to know type classes more intimately, but I've hit a bit of a roadblock. For whatever reason I'm not allowed to make an instance of my `Vector` class. I'm being told that it's an illegal instance declaration because I don't have distinct type variables? What's going on here?

```
class Vector v where
  vplus :: v -> v -> v
  vmult :: Num a => v -> a -> v

instance Num a => Vector (a, a) where
  (a, b) `vplus` (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
  (a, b) `vmult` m = (a * m, b * m)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` in you `(a,a)` instance will be one arbitrary `Num` instance. The `a` in `vmult :: Num a => v -> a -> v` knows nothing about this, i.e. this may be any *other* `Num` instance.

To make the class work you need to either

- ensure that the number types can be converted into each other. For instance,

  ```
  class Vector v where
    vplus :: v -> v -> v
    vmult :: RealFrac a => v -> a -> v

  instance RealFrac a => Vector (a, a) where
    (a, b) `vplus` (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
    (a, b) `vmult` m' = (a * m, b * m)
      where m = realToFrac m'
  ```
- make sure the scalar multiplicators are actually the same type as the vector components. This is how the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) library does it. For your code, it would take on the form

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

  class Vector v where
    type Scalar v :: *
    vplus :: v -> v -> v
    vmult :: v -> Scalar v -> v

  instance Num a => Vector (a, a) where
    type Scalar (a,a) = a
    (a, b) `vplus` (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
    (a, b) `vmult` m = (a * m, b * m)
  ```

Comment: I get an "illegal family declaration" if I do the `type Scalar v :: *` in the class

Comment: also doing like they did in vector-space doesn't actually remove the error at all.. even after enabling type families

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: yes it does. (My original post did introduce _another_ error, admittedly, as I had copied the `realToFrac` from the other solution which is obviously wrong here.)

Comment: I seem to be getting a few errors when I try to do `vplus (1, 2) (3, 4)` saying "No instance for (Vector (t0, t1)) arising from use of 'vplus'", and "No instance for (Num t1) arising from literal '2'". What's going on here?

Comment: I've expanded my question

Comment: I daresay that expansion doesn't belong here, please ask a new question. Anyway, the problem is not so bad. In your example, it's sufficient to write ``(2::Int, 3::Int) `vdot` (5, 5)``. The compiler _will_ need a precise hint as to the type of one of the vectors, but in real code, that's generally a no-brainer because you're only dealing with variables that GHC can somehow trace to a top-level function type signature.

Comment: made it a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435306/couldnt-match-expected-type-with-actual-type-the-type-variables-are-ambiguous)