# Couldn't match expected type with actual type. The type variables are ambiguous

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass, type-families

Trying to create a `Vector` typeclass that works on tuples I've run into some problems

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Vector v where
  type Scalar v :: *
  vplus :: v -> v -> v
  vmult :: v -> Scalar v -> v
  vdot  :: v -> v -> Scalar v

instance Num a => Vector (a, a) where
  type Scalar (a,a) = a
  (a, b) `vplus` (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
  (a, b) `vmult` m = (a * m, b * m)
  (a, b) `vdot`  (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

The problem is that I need explicit type declarations for GHC to not get confused. This is of course a minor inconvenience, except `vdot` doesn't seem to want to work at all.

```
res :: Int
res = (2, 3) `vdot` (5, 5)
-- error: Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'Scalar (t0, t1)'
--        The type variables 't0', 't1' are ambiguous
```

This error does go away if I do this:

```
res :: Int
res = ((2, 3) :: (Int, Int)) `vdot` (5, 5)
```

But now we've reached the realm of verbose code so extreme it just isn't practical anymore. Haskell's supposed to be beautiful and concise; not explicit type hell

I would have assumed GHC was capable of resolving `type Scalar (a, a) = a` on its own, but the error persists even if I remove the instance declaration completely. It even complains when `Vector (Int, Int)` is the only instance available.

So what's going on here? And is there a way to get this to work beautifully?

Answer (score 3):

In

```
res :: Int
res = (2, 3) `vdot` (5, 5)
```

nothing forces `2` and `3` to be `Int`, or even to be the same type as each other. So, the `Vector (a, a)` instance might not apply. For all GHC knows you could intend to write another instance `Vector (Float, Double)` with `type Scalar (Float, Double) = Int` and a totally different implementation of `vdot`, and `res` would still type check. Hence the types of `2` and `3` are ambiguous, as GHC told you.

It sounds like you really want to say: a pair `(a, b)` can *only* be an instance of `Vector` when `b` is the same type as `a` (and then use the instance you wrote). You can express that in GHC as follows:

```
instance (a ~ b, Num a) => Vector (a, b) where
  type Scalar (a,b) = a
  (a, b) `vplus` (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
  (a, b) `vmult` m = (a * m, b * m)
  (a, b) `vdot`  (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

`a ~ b` is an equality constraint that asserts that the two types `a` and `b` are the same.

Now your example `res` can work correctly:

```
*Main> (2, 3) `vdot` (5, 5) :: Int
25
```

Here is the reasoning that means that the types are no longer ambiguous.

- `vdot` has type `Vector v => v -> v -> Scalar v`. So for `res` to type check, we need to find the `v` such that `(2, 3) :: v`, `(5, 5) :: v`, and `Scalar v ~ Int`.
- But `(2, 3)` has a type of the form `(a, b)` and there is an instance whose head is of the form `Vector (a, b)`. So, we must use that instance. (In your original program, we cannot make this step because there is no sufficiently general instance.)
- The associated type definition of that instance tells us that `Scalar (a, b) ~ a`. But we know `Scalar (a, b)` was supposed to be `Int`, so we must have `a ~ Int`.
- The constraints of that instance tell us `a ~ b` and that there should be an instance `Num a`. So, we must have `b ~ Int` too (and indeed `Num Int` holds).
- So, we concluded that `2 :: Int` and `3 :: Int`, and since `(5, 5) :: v` also, we have `5 :: Int` and `5 :: Int` too.
- Now we've determined which type class to use for every overloaded name in our expression (`2`, `3`, `5`, `5` and `vdot`), so there is no ambiguity and we can finally evaluate the expression.

Comment: I would've thought that if it says `Scalar (a, a)` and `Vector (a, a)` that the only possible type available is `a`. So if `a` is an Int, every other instance of `a` must _also_ be Int

Comment: I think you're just assuming that your `Vector (a, a)` instance will be selected. The point is there's nothing that forces it to be selected and, in fact, you could add a second, non-overlapping instance that would also type check if used in `res`. GHC never "just assumes" an instance will be selected just because it has the instance available, it needs to find the instance using the logic outlined in the second half of my answer.

Comment: but if it's the only available instance, how then does it not necessarily select that one? Isn't it kinda like having a square-shaped hole and a square that can't go in because it might be a circle?

Comment: Since type classes are open (anyone can define additional instances anywhere), the compiler never assumes that it has full information about what instances exist. So, the `Vector (a, a)` might not be the only available instance that would fit. In practical terms, this means the compiler won't let you write programs that can become ambiguous if you (or modules that you import) define additional, non-overlapping instances.

Comment: Your analogy is poorly constructed. It's not the piece, but rather the hole whose shape is unknown, or flexible. We don't want to commit to putting the square-shaped piece in today because we might get a different piece that would fit equally well in the mail tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the matter:

```
class Vector v where
  type Scalar v :: *
  vdot  :: v -> v -> Scalar v
  ...    
instance Num a => Vector (a, a) where
  type Scalar (a,a) = a
  ...
res :: Int
res = (2, 3) `vdot` (5, 5)
```

Now, we have

```
vdot :: v     -> v  -> Scalar v
vdot    (2,3) (5,5)
```

so the double application must have this type

```
(2,3) :: v
(5,5) :: v
res = vdot (2,3) (5,5) :: Scalar v
```

Expanding the type of the pairs:

```
(2,3) :: (a1, a2) ~ v     for some a1, a2 in class Num
(5,5) :: (b1, b2) ~ v     for some b1, b2 in class Num
res = vdot (2,3) (5,5) :: Scalar v
```

By transitivity, `(a1, a2) ~ (b1, b2)`, hence `a1 ~ b1` and `a2 ~ b2`.

```
(2,3) :: (a1, a2)         for some a1, a2 in class Num
(5,5) :: (a1, a2)
res = vdot (2,3) (5,5) :: Scalar (a1, a2)
```

We also know from the annotation that

```
res :: Int
```

hence

```
Scalar (a1, a2) ~ Int
```

But from this there's no way to know what are `a1, a2`. After all, one might use custom types for that:

```
data A1 = ...
data A2 = ...
instance Num A1 where ...
instance Num A2 where ...
instance Vector (A1, A2) where
   type Scalar (A1, A2) = Int  -- !!!!
```

Note the last `Int`. This causes both

```
type Scalar (Int, Int) = Int
type Scalar (A1 , A2 ) = Int
```

making it impossible to choose the types of `a1, a2`. This is usually referred by the sentence "*type families do not have to be injective*".

Also note that the absence of the `instance Vector (A1, A2)` in your code does not help. GHC must compile your code expecting such instance to be declared later on, possibly in other modules (the "open world" assumption). This is pretty much required to allow for separate compilation.